# Chef gitのリポジトリを取得していないのに(up to date)と表示されてチェックアウトできない

Tags: chef, rbenv

Chefでruby環境を構築するにあたり、gitリソースを使ってrbenvを下記のレシピの通りチェックアウトしようとしていますが何故か`* git[/home/ops/.rbenv] action checkout (up to date)`と表示されスルーされてしまいます。

レシピの該当箇所は以下のようになっています。

```
git '/home/test-user/.rbenv' do
  repository 'git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git'
  reference 'master'
  action :checkout
  user 'test-user'
  group 'test-user'
end
```

ちなみに`ruby-build`は下記レシピとなっていますがちゃんと取得できています。

```
git '/home/ops/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build' do
  repository 'git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git'
  reference 'master'
  action :checkout
  user 'test-user'
  group 'test-user'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決できました。
チェックアウト先のフォルダが作成されている場合、リポジトリチェックアウト済みと判断してしまうようなので
チェックアウト先のフォルダを作成せずに同じレシピを適用させたらうまくいきました。